# Xmpp connection failed with smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I currently have an android application in which I use the smack library to connect to my XMPP server. This application has already worked in the past, but since today, my tablet could not connect to the server.

On the line :

```
connection.connect();
```

I got this error :

```
W/System.err﹕ org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '192.168.57.100:5222' failed because java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.57.100 (port 5222) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:596)
07-08 11:46:19.730  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:830)
07-08 11:46:19.730  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
07-08 11:46:19.730  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at com.crisalid.EcranCuisine.PosteFabActivity$XMPPAsyncTask.doInBackground(PosteFabActivity.java:583)
07-08 11:46:19.730  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at com.crisalid.EcranCuisine.PosteFabActivity$XMPPAsyncTask.doInBackground(PosteFabActivity.java:284)
07-08 11:46:19.730  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-08 11:46:19.730  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-08 11:46:19.731  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-08 11:46:19.731  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-08 11:46:19.731  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-08 11:46:19.731  13812-14023/com.crisalid.EcranCuisine W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

There is strange things append : I installed this application on my tablet and on my phone. With exactly the same configuration, I don't get this error on my phone but I'm getting it on my tablet.

I already tried to disable/ enable my wifi on the tablet but nothings changes. 
I checked if the server was up, and it is working.

Have you any idea ?

Comment: *but since tomorrow* :) back to the future? of course it is a network environment(hardware/setup) error ...

Comment: since today sorry. If it's a network environment error, the application shouldn't work on none of my device no ?

Comment: but error is obvious:  192.168.57.100 is not reachable from the device ... so, device is connected to the different/not routed network like other WIFI or even 3g connection ... setup some web server on 192.168.57.100 then use browser on device and check if is working ...

Comment: I disabled the 3g on my phone, and I connected my phone and the tablet on the same network. I'm able to connect to the xmpp server with the phone, but not with the tablet. Reboot the routeur can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selvin were right, with my tablet I was connected to te right wifi but dhcp was attributing me a wrong ip. 
On my tablet the ip was 10.20.64.152 so it wasn't on the good network (which is 192.168.57.*).

The solution was to set a static ip.